# Select a column from an xarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

How do you select a column from an `xarray.DataArray` please? This is how I am doing the xarray

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = np.random.rand(5,2)
da = xr.DataArray(my_data, 
                  coords={'my_id':np.arange(my_data.shape[0]),
                         'columns': ['x', 'y']},
                  dims=['my_id', 'columns'])
```

and I want to select `column x`. If that was a `dataframe`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=['x','y'])
```

i am looking for the equivalent of `df['x']`

Am I defining the `DataArray` the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok, i think i got it:

```
da.sel(columns='x')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas-like `.loc` as suggested in [docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html):

```
da.loc[:, ['x']]

<xarray.DataArray (my_id: 5, columns: 1)>
array([[ 0.534358],
       [ 0.113875],
       [ 0.905085],
       [ 0.96994 ],
       [ 0.548338]])
Coordinates:
  * my_id    (my_id) int32 0 1 2 3 4
  * columns  (columns) <U1 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the docs: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_pandas.html

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = np.random.rand(5,2)
da = xr.DataArray(my_data, 
                  coords={'my_id':np.arange(my_data.shape[0]),
                         'columns': ['x', 'y']},
                  dims=['my_id', 'columns'])

df = da.to_pandas()

df['x']
```

**Result**

df['x']

```
Out[27]: 
my_id
0    0.752056
1    0.048029
2    0.145835
3    0.083147
4    0.618351
Name: x, dtype: float64
```